# xlsread only the first row

Tags: excel, matlab

From matlab I wish to read only the first row from an excel sheet but do not know the number of columns in the sheet. i.e I want to do the equivalent of

```
filename = 'myExample.xlsx';

columnB = xlsread(filename,'B:B') .
```

Would be grateful to know the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
firstrow = xlsread(filename, '1:1')
```

should do it.